# Could not resolve dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have been trying to download a template to start customizing it. Upon downloading it, one is supposed to install all local dependencies using `npm install` or `yarn install`. I have done both of those and I have gotten the same error both times. Moreover I have tried using the same command with `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps`, as advised in the error message. I found a GitHub issue discussing this precise problem and some other stack overflow threads. I have tried everything I have come across, and it is just not working. Moreover I have installed the recommended version of node, so that is not the problem either, as suggested in a different thread.

The error message can be seen below.

```
While resolving: @mui/material@5.2.0
npm ERR! Found: @emotion/react@11.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!   @emotion/react@"11.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.3.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     @emotion/styled@"11.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       @mui/material@"5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@mui/icons-material)
npm ERR!     1 more (@mui/styled-engine)
npm ERR!   1 more (@mui/styled-engine)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @emotion/react@11.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     @mui/material@"5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!       @mui/icons-material@"5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

The template: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard-react?ref=readme-mdr#

GitHub issue: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react/issues/171

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the specific version of `@emotion/react` used in the template, is not working anymore.

To solve the problem I went to the `package.json` and changed the version from `11.4.1` to `11.5.0` manually. Seems that the `11.5.0` solves the problem with the template used.

Comment: Instead changing manually the version, you should use the `npm i @emotion/react@11.5.0 --save` approach.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your version from package.json file and run again "npm install" command

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while not in the folder of my react app.  Cd into it and should be good but I am positive you found this answer by now or stumbled upon it like me.  Best wishes

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.